# Open port in ubuntu box issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, port, iptables

I have run this command  ten times (and rebooted the box after):

```
   sudo  iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
```

I have tried:

```
sudo ufw allow 5432
```

And running:

```
ufw status
```

I got result:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

But  5432 port is still not open.

What is missing?

Comment: Have you running a service on port 5432?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical PostgreSQL installation has listen='localhost' in postgresql.conf. You have to change it to listen='*' to listen on other interfaces.

Also, iptables -A adds rule to end of queue. It's possible, that you are blocking connection in previous rules.

Comment: Thanks. It is the postgresql config!